# Get <tr> value from id with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, html-table

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example" >
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Project Code</th> 
            <th>Project Name</th> 
            <th>Project REF ID</th> 
            <th>Effective Date</th> 
            <th>Close Date</th> 
            <th>Last Update Date</th>
            <th>Creation Date</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>Last Update By</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 

        <?php 
        //error_log(print_r($project,false));

        for($i=0;$i<count($project);$i++)
        { ?>
            <tr class="project_id"  value="<?php echo $project[$i]   ['project_id']; ?>">

            <td><?php echo $project[$i]['project_code']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['project_name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['project_ref_id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['effective_date']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['close_date']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['last_update_date']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['creation_date']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['created_by']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['last_update_by']; ?></td>
                <td><img class="edit" >src="http://spsvn01/RAIDLOG/application/assets/img/file_edit.png" alt="edit" >border=1 height=20 width=20> 

                    <img class="delete" >src="http://spsvn01/RAIDLOG/application/assets/img/notification_error.png" >alt="delete" border=1 height=20 width=20>
                </td>
             </tr>
        <?php } ?>




     </tbody>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   var table=  $('#example').dataTable(
                {
                "columnDefs": [
                    { "width": "10%", "targets": 0 }]
                });


    $('.delete').click(function () {
        var project_id = $('.project_id').val();
        alert(project_id);
  });           

} );
</script>
```

Please I want to get my tr value and I don't even know how to do..

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
var project_id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('.value');
   alert(project_id);
});
.attr('value'); not .attr('.value');
```

this work fine.

Comment: Thanks, now I have my value. But for any row where I click on delete button. Alert shown me the first row's value :-(

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the `value` attribute value of the `tr` ancestor element of the clicked element so

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
  var project_id = $(this).closest('tr').attr('.value');
  alert(project_id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i want to show this value in my " alert(project_id);" an undefined value appear

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax issues in your HTML i.e. some closing tag errors and miss-usage of `""`. Well, if we talk about your question, Why don't you simply make your own Javascript Function and call it where you want, pass it whatever you like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleterow(project_id){
    alert(project_id);
}
</script>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example">
    <thead> 
        <tr> 
            <th>Project Code</th> 
            <th>Project Name</th> 
            <th>Project REF ID</th> 
            <th>Effective Date</th> 
            <th>Close Date</th> 
            <th>Last Update Date</th>
            <th>Creation Date</th>
            <th>Created By</th>
            <th>Last Update By</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr> 
    </thead> 
    <tbody> 

        <?php 
        //error_log(print_r($project,false));

        for($i=0;$i<count($project);$i++){?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['project_code']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['project_name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['project_ref_id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['effective_date']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['close_date']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['last_update_date']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['creation_date']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['created_by']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $project[$i]['last_update_by']; ?></td>
                <td>
                    <img class="edit" src="http://spsvn01/RAIDLOG/application/assets/img/file_edit.png" alt="edit" border="1" height="20" width="20"/> 

                    <?php
                    // if you have string in 'project_id' use this IMG TAG.
                    ?>
                    <img class="delete" src="http://spsvn01/RAIDLOG/application/assets/img/notification_error.png" alt="delete" border="1" height="20" width="20" onclick="myfunction('<?php echo $project[$i]['project_id']; ?>');"/>

                    <?php
                    // if you have an integer in 'project_id' use this IMG TAG.
                    ?>
                    <img class="delete" src="http://spsvn01/RAIDLOG/application/assets/img/notification_error.png" alt="delete" border="1" height="20" width="20" onclick="deleterow(<?php echo $project[$i]['project_id']; ?>);"/>
                </td>
             </tr>
        <?php } ?>




     </tbody>

</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable({
        "columnDefs": [{
            "width": "10%",
            "targets": 0
        }]
    });
} );

</script>
```

> Please read my comments, in above code.

Comment: Great idea, it's a better way I think too. But when I click the firefox debugger told me "myfunction is not defined"

Comment: Please check my update, if it doesn't work. Try to check if your `<?php echo $project[$i]['project_id']; ?>` is showing that id or not.

Comment: I have checked my value and it's an integer. But the problem come from the function. It doesn't call the fonction. I have this issue :           **(index):225 Uncaught ReferenceError: deleterow is not defined**                  Thanks for your time

Comment: var deleterow = function(project_id){
     alert(project_id);
     
     
    }

Comment: Check my update, I have changed the usage, and please try to Inspect your HTML in the browser, press `F12` to see the Inspect window. Your HTML should look like this `<img src="..." onclick="deleterow(10)" />`

Comment: Thanks a lot bro !!!!!! You made my day, i'm working on that since this morning...

Comment: Glad to know that it worked for you @NassimRebhi :) Don't forget to Mark this answer as Correct and also when you like some comment try to Upvote it too :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
  var project_id = $(this).parents('tr').attr('value');
  alert(project_id);
});
```

or

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
  var project_id = $($(this).parents('tr')).attr('value');
  alert(project_id);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but when i want to show this value in my " alert(project_id);" an undefined value appear –

Comment: are you sure your value is store in value property ?

Comment: Yes I see my value when I inspect the html code on my web page

Comment: I have checked both of them : (

Comment: You have check with parents instate of parent ?

Comment: because if you check with parent than it will give you undefined error because parent is the <td> but if try with parents than it will work.